# SQL How to subtract one column based on criteria from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to subtract this data based on year in the other column to make a new column.
The data looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|value|year|
+-----+-----+
| 2658| 2020|
| 4234| 2019|
| 5435| 2018|
+-----+-----+
```

And I would like to get an output like this, from say the 2019 - 2020 values:

```
+---------+
|new_value|
+---------+
| 1576| 
+--------+
```

I would also not like to make a new tables or anything. Also preferably using CTEs or a way to put into a larger query easily .

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ? Please do not spam the tag

Comment: please put sample output properly

Comment: Use the LAG analytic function

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when year = 2019 then value else - value end)
from t
where year in (2019, 2020);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this (untested):

```
SELECT l.value - r.value as new_value
FROM my_table l 
JOIN my_table r ON (l.year=2019 AND r.year=2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't just want 2019/2020, join the table to itself using an off by one join

```
SELECT b.value - a.value 
FROM t a
  JOIN t b ON a.year + 1 = b.year
```